# Validate a SAML Response in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, saml-2.0

I need to validate a SAML response from an IdP that is passed/forwarded from the recipient SP to a node server.

Are there any npm packages that  just validate the SAML response without re-contacting the IdP?

Most packages like passport-saml seem to handle everything (including contacting the IdP).

I've tried the saml20 package, but continue to receive an assertion invalid error. I've checked both the response (rawAssertion) and cert captured from within the saml20 package and those validate fine using the online samltools validator.

Comment: do you want to compare XML response ?

Comment: Trying to validate the SAML signature. I didn't think you could do that through a simple XML comparison, but I'm new SAML. Could you explain how you mean?

Comment: are u trying to implement some AD login ?? using IdP/SP